# SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Users_Companies_CompanyId"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to add a new user in my database but take the exception. Unfortunately I'm new to both SQL Server and EF, but searching for the answer made me understand that the problem is somewhere in the SQL Server tables and impossibility of connection user and company there. Should I do something with `Id` or `CompanyId` or what?

> **SqlException**: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Users_Companies_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in database "companiesdb", table "dbo.Companies", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.

Code:

```
public class User
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; } // for what???
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; } //for what?
}

public class Company
{
        public int Id { get; set; } //for what?
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Company()
        {
            Users = new List<User>();
        }
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataApp1.Models
{
    public class UserDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } //create db for users
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; } //and for companies they belong
        public UserDb(DbContextOptions<UserDb> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have told to your database that a relationship exists between a user and a company. Something like 'A user is employeed by a company and a company employees many users'. Then I suppose you are trying to add a user without giving the required reference to  a company (or a reference to a non existant company)

Comment: Yes, I get it bur how can I put required reference to a company and show this straight connect between user and company?

Comment: Start writing the code to add companies to your companies table. Then when writing code for adding/modifying a user load some kind of user interface object with a list of companies already saved. Finally require every user to have a company id extracted from your companies list

Answer (score 1):

Your User class, which apparently relates to your Users table, has a field for CompanyId. Based on the error, your database requires a correct company ID to be added to the DB every time.

If you have not added the company to the Companies table before adding a User, the insert will fail with this error. If you insert the User with no value in the CompanyId field, this error will occur.

So, your correct program flow would be:

- Add Company to Companies if it doesn't exist there
- Get the correct CompanyId
- Add the CompanyId to the CompanyId field in the User record before saving it.

Comment: (thank you) but what should I do w column Id in Companies as a private key?Problem is there (The conflict occurred in database "companiesdb", table "dbo.Companies", column 'Id'.)

Comment: If your foreign key is in the Companies table, then it is designed incorrectly. This should be a foreign key in the Users table pointing at the Companies table, so when you insert into the Users table, it looks inside the Companies table for a record with the Company ID you inserted. If it doesn't exist, then it returns this error. Also, you said that you were adding a new User. Thus the problem should be on the Insert into the Users table. The FK reference pattern is confusing, but the statement "The conflict occurred in" refers to the reference DB, not the DB being inserted into.

Comment: If you are still having difficulties, you can look at what value is being sent to SQL in your insert statement for CompanyId. Then check the Company table to see if it exists.